# Torch: the implementation of embedding layer

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I'm a beginner of torch and I'm reading the code of LSTM language models. I'm confused on the implementation of embedding layer (https://github.com/oxford-cs-ml-2015/practical6/blob/master/Embedding.lua).

This is the `updateGradInput` function in embedding layer:

```
function Embedding:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
  if self.gradInput then
    self.gradInput:resize(input:size())
    return self.gradInput
  end
end
```

My first question is why there is a `if` statement in this function rather than just like below:

```
function Embedding:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
  self.gradInput:resize(input:size())
  return self.gradInput
end
```

I think `self.gradInput` will always be true because `self.gradInput` was initialized in `__init()` of `nn.Module`.

My second question is why `return self.gradInput` directly instead of calculates `self.gradInput` using `input` and `gradOutput`? I mean `self.gradInput = gradOutput * (deriv. of output wrt input)`.

My last question is what the effect of this code in [Embedding.lua](https://github.com/oxford-cs-ml-2015/practical6/blob/master/Embedding.lua):

```
-- we do not need to accumulate parameters when sharing
Embedding.sharedAccUpdateGradParameters = Embedding.accUpdateGradParameters
```

What does it mean of "we do not need to accumulate parameters when sharing"?

Answer (score 0):

(1) is so that if someone explicitly nils gradInput, then dont compute it
(2) is because embedding layers don't actually have a gradInput, the inputs are not differentiable